# Solidity - How can I start to understand the bytecode in order to call a function of a deployed smart contract?

Tags: solidity

I can go through the opcodes for the parts of the bytecode, but I don't understand how to figure out how to call a deployed contract. Somewhat new to ethereum and solidiy, any help is appreciated. For example:

0x60806040526040518060400160405280600c81526020017f696e697469616c697365643100000000000000000000000000000000000000008152506000908051906020019061004f9291906100ae565b506040518...

Answer (score 0):

You realy don't need to understand this. To call deployed contract you need to have either it's code or abi and address.

Then you create your contract and call it through that.

Like this

```
import "contractYouWantToInteractWith.sol";

contract Interact {
    contractYouWantToInteractWith public contract = contractYouWantToInteractWith(addressOfTheContract);

// Then just call on it like this

    function interact() public {
        contract.FUNCTIONFROMTHECONTRACT(inputs);
    }

}
```

Comment: I do `address(contractAddress).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("setter(string)", param));` in order to set a value.

setter(string) is supposed to exist, it also has a getter() which is supposed to returns the same value that's defined in an interface. But the getter doesn't return this value. I can't figure out what's wrong with the way I call it.